# Why are questions with clear examples downvoted for simply not knowing what people are asking about

Tags: discussion

This question has a negative score when it can easily be discerned what is being asked and if you don't know the terminology it is hard to find the information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095690/what-is-this-custom-attribute-filter-tag-for-and-how-is-it-used-in-mvc

The question is clear, and the answer is too. Why the downvotes?

Comment: _Who knows...._

Comment: `if you don't know the terminology it is hard to find the information` Considering the question *uses* the correct terminology, clearly that's not applicable here.  Since they *do* know the correct terminology, they can *easily* find the relevant information on the topic.

Comment: @Forklift The original revision of the question also contains the appropriate term.

Comment: That someone can figure out how to answer a post does not make it a) a good quality and well-researched question, and b) on topic. We are building a knowledge base for future visitors, that you get help in the process is a nice bonus but not the actual goal. If a post doesn't meet the goal of being helpful to future visitors (so including a clear problem statement and sharing their research to provide a clear context), then downvotes are an appropriate response.

Comment: The question is far from clear. Put it this way: suppose the OP hadn't been asking about attributes, but instead asking about classes. The question would have said "What does this class do?" and shown a reference to a `WhatIsThisClass` class. For any specific attribute, you look at the documentation for that attribute.

Comment: If you wish to put it that way I would say the user understood it might be taken as ambiguous and made the best effort he could to present the question as clearly as possible given that he was not aware of the correct terminology. We clearly disagree and I'm happy to collect my downvotes and move on.

Comment: @Forklift That they *tried* to ask a clear question doesn't mean that they *succeeded* in asking a clear question.  If a question isn't clear, it merits closure as "unclear", no matter how much the OP tried to clarify it.  And again, the OP *wasn't* unaware of the terminology.  The original revision of the question used the appropriate terminology, so that had all of the means at their disposal to find more information about those terms though a simple google search.  They simply choose not to bother, which makes it a bad question.

Comment: @JonSkeet To be fair, and fwiw, I actually didn't read it as a question about that specific attribute. Quoting the original revision: *"What is the custom attribute tag on top of a method (like the below example) used for"* I interpreted the indefinite article in that sentence (*the* vs. *this*) and the indication that the snippet was just an example to mean that the author was asking about custom attributes in general. What they probably *should* have done, though, was call it `[ExampleCustomAttribute]`, the `This` may have added ambiguity.

Comment: @JasonC: And the point is that for any specific attribute, you'd read the documentation... just as you would for any class, or a method of a class. A question of "What does an unspecified attribute do" is pointless IMO.

Answer (score 20):

There are multiple reasons to downvote a question, lack of clarity is not the only one. The tooltip for the downvote button reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

In this particular case it would've been lack of research effort, which is a fairly common and generally accepted reason for casting a downvote.

To put it in perspective, I've never written a line of C# in my life, and just now I did a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+custom+attribute) which yielded enough information that I could have posted a correct and valid answer. It took me under 10 seconds -- probably less time than it took the author to write that question.

So, yeah, the question is crystal clear, but it lacks basic research effort.

The oft-linked [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Help Center article has a good basic rundown of what is generally expected, in this case the first section "Search, and research" is relevant. That Help Center article is a good representation of current community values and policy, so if you're ever wondering why a question may have been poorly received, compare it to some of the guidelines there to get an idea.